# Checking common property values shared among all the items

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

```
List<List<Products>>MainList 

    MainList[Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4]

    Item1.Product[{name= A, etc}, {name= B, etc}, {name= C, etc}]
    Item2.Product[{name= A, etc}, {name= B, etc}, {name= C, etc}]
    Item3.Product[{name= A, etc}, {name= B, etc}, {name= C, etc}]
    Item4.Product[{name= A, etc}, {name= B, etc}, {name= C, etc}]
```

- A,B,C refers to a value of a property called "Name"
- Product is a list of product items.

I want to know a way that I can identify whether the Name property of each and every list item in the main list is 100% equals. 
    Which means the A, B, C are shared among the name property of all the items in the main list.

Can you guys please help me to solve this using c#?

Comment: Rather than using pseudo-code, could you provide a [mcve] that we could use to understand the problem better?

Comment: what do you mean by 100% equals? do you want to group object which have same value in `Name` Property?

Comment: That all have the same name? `MainList.All(x => x.Name == MainList[0].Name)`

Comment: Did you miss some punctuation in the title. (what is an “item lists are 100% similar”, that this list is full of)? **You need to proof read title and body.** also is List greater than MainList, or does it inherit from, or …, what is ex-, …

Comment: You should meet my friend, [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since your code sample is pseudo-code, I had to guess on an actual implementation. I hope I preserved the essence of the structure you are presenting.

If so, the following uses the Zip and SequenceEqual to solve your problem. The Zip allows for comparing consecutive ProductCategory objects and the SequenceEqual compares the lists of Products between the two ProductCategory objects

```cs
void Main()
{
    var catalogue = 
        new List<ProductCategory>
        {
            new ProductCategory { Title = "1", Products = new List<Product> { new Product { Name = "A" }, new Product { Name = "B" }, new Product { Name = "C" }, } },
            new ProductCategory { Title = "2", Products = new List<Product> { new Product { Name = "A" }, new Product { Name = "B" }, new Product { Name = "C" }, } },
            new ProductCategory { Title = "3", Products = new List<Product> { new Product { Name = "A" }, new Product { Name = "B" }, new Product { Name = "C" }, } },
            new ProductCategory { Title = "4", Products = new List<Product> { new Product { Name = "A" }, new Product { Name = "B" }, new Product { Name = "C" }, } },
        };

    var allEqual = catalogue
        .Skip(1)
        .Zip(catalogue, (x, y) => x.Products.SequenceEqual(y.Products, new ProductComparer()))
        .All(c => c);

    Console.WriteLine($"This is equal: {allEqual}");
}


public class ProductCategory
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int hashProductName = product.Name == null ? 0 : product.Name.GetHashCode();

        return hashProductName;
    }
}
```